# Drag & drop on UITextView in iOS 11

Tags: ios11

I have an editable UITextView. When I drag text from this view and drop it onto itself, the text moves but the following two methods are not called:

```
textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:
textViewDidChange:
```

What should I do if I want to perform some tasks (for examples, registering undo or updating the associated UIDocument) after the text has moved? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your textView's textDragDelegate to self and implement

```
- (void)textDraggableView:(UIView<UITextDraggable> *)textDraggableView dragSessionDidEnd:(id<UIDragSession>)session withOperation:(UIDropOperation)operation;
```

or another suitable method from UITextDragDelegate.

**Edit:**

Actually in your case textDropDelegate may be a better solution as the new text may come from another app.

A suitable method from there seems to be

```
- (void)textDroppableView:(UIView<UITextDroppable> *)textDroppableView willPerformDrop:(id<UITextDropRequest>)drop;
```

Comment: In fact, your original suggestion, i.e., textDraggableView:dragSessionDidEnd:withOperation:, solves my problem. My text view only allows move operation for text dragged from itself. Therefore, it can tell whether the text is from itself by checking the operation argument. I was not aware of this method.

Comment: But, I still feel confused why the drop operation does not trigger textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:
and textViewDidChange:. It does not make any sense.